# if statement with geting the last character of a String in Android Studio java

Tags: java, android, string, android-studio, if-statement

My code need the if statement to see the last character of some string but how many time i try nothing happens, that mean the conduction is false !.

my code:

```
            String zzz = T2.getText().toString();
            String zz = zzz.substring(zzz.length() - 1);

            String oo = "+";
            if ( zz ==  oo){         
                T1.setText(" the result ");
            } 
            ..
            String Add1 = T1.getText().toString();
            AAAA11111 = AAAA11111 + Double.parseDouble(Add1);
            T2.setText(Double.toString(AAAA11111) + " +"); // the last character is "+" and it's what i needed
            ..
```

Answer (score 3):

For `string` comparison use `equals` method:

```
zz.equals(oo)
```

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java) you will find a very good explanation about the difference between using the `"=="` operator and the `equals` method for string comparison.

Comment: thanks, it works now , and I will never use"  == " again :(

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to check the last character of the string, It also works!

```
char lastChar = zzz.charAt(zzz.length() - 1);

if (lastChar == '+') {
    // Do something
}
```

Comment: By the way, I think the difference between equals() and == operator is bad boilerplate code of Java.. (Not support to operator overloading) Many developers make mistakes for that.

Comment: it doesn't working in android java but the "equals" worked, thank you all